# Bounded time synchronizer

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

I understand the role of a synchronizer is to make sure the input satisfies the dynamic discipline of registers. How does the above synchronizer fix that problem exactly? (What's the basic idea behind it?)
The information for the slide is found at:https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c6/c6s1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synchronizer *doesn't* fix the problem. That's the point.

With an input that fails setup or hold, some percentage of the time the flip-flop will have an unknown state.  The 'unknown' state is sometimes called *metastable*, where the flop fails to properly resolve to a 1 or 0.

More about all that here: http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/metastablity.html

How often a metastable event occurs depends on the data rate, the clock rate and, how 'crunchy' (metastable-hard) the flip flop is. Flops designed to be metastable-hard have low internal delays, that is, the window between setup and hold is small.

The failure rate for a flip-flop can be computed as follows:

- MTBF = 1 / (Fin * Fclk * Td)

Where:

- Fin = signal input frequency
- Fclk = clock frequency
- Td = flop propogation delay (Setup/hold window)

It is possible to use multiple synchronizers in series to mitigate the results of metastability in the first flop. But it will always be there.